# LinkedIn Video API initializeUpload error: UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY

Tags: linkedin-api

As of yesterday I started to get this error when uploading a video to LinkedIn.
I migrated recently to their new Videos API and Posts API and it was working fine until yesterday.

The error I get:

```
{
  "description": "owner value urn:li:organization:<id> is of type organization. Allowed URN types are company, member",
  "input": {
    "inputPath": {
      "fieldPath": "/initializeUploadRequest/owner"
    }
  },
  "code": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY"
}
```

So the owner urn seems right since there can be only `urn:li:person:<id>` or `urn:li:organization:<id>` according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2022-06&tabs=http#schema):
[image]

The request made is pretty simple:

```
const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videos?action=initializeUpload';
const headers = {
   Authorization: `Bearer <token>`,
  'LinkedIn-Version': '202206',
  'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
};
const initializeUploadRequest = {
      owner: 'url:li:organization:<id>',
      fileSizeBytes: <size>,
      uploadThumbnail: true,
      uploadCaptions: false
}
return await axios.post(url, { initializeUploadRequest }, { headers });
```

Has anyone experienced this lately?
It was working fine prior to yesterday :/

Comment: LinkedIn api's are the worst I have ever seen in 20 years, complete mess...

Comment: I think its urn:li:organization not url:li:organization